# Can I close tickets on OTRS through e-mail like Trac does?

Tags: otrs

I'm setting up a new helpdesk and one of the main features of Trac is that you can manage tickets through e-mail tags, is there any way of doing this through OTRS?

Answer (score 2):

OTRS has Postmaster Filters that you can use to grab values from incoming emails and make ticket actions from it. You'll have obviously have most success typically if you process emails from an automated source.

An alternative would be to use email-headers, where you can send an email header like X-OTRS-State with a value of 'Closed' to update the ticket state.